# Unknown column in 'on clause' where actual value filters are used

Tags: mysql, sql

I am generating this query with knex with MYSQL and it's giving `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '5025052' in 'on clause'`.  How can I get it to work?

**POINT**: There are related question around this issue but they seem not to involve a case with filtering with actual field values e.g `t1.user_id = "5025052"`. I was advised to include all filters in `join clause` instead of using `where clouse` for some performance reasons. If not true, am ready to learn.

```sql
SELECT 
    `t1`.*, `users`.`phone`, `users`.`email`
FROM
    `t1`
        INNER JOIN
    `users` ON `users`.`id` = `t1`.`user_id`
        AND `t1`.`user_id` = `5025052`
        AND `t1`.`deleted` = 0
        AND `users`.`deleted` = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks are for escaping column and table name - not for values.

Replace

```
AND `t1`.`user_id` = `5025052`
```

with

```
AND `t1`.`user_id` = 5025052
```

or if it is a `varchar` field then use quotes

```
AND `t1`.`user_id` = '5025052'
```

And there is no need (and uncommon) to put all conditions in the `join` clause. So you could also do:

```
SELECT t1.*, users.phone, users.email
FROM t1
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = t1.user_id
WHERE t1.user_id = '5025052'
  AND t1.deleted = 0
  AND users.deleted = 0;
```

When using [knex](https://knexjs.org/), you can remove unnecessary backticks with `knex.raw()`.

Comment: doing it this minute... pretty fast response!!

Comment: Note the user_id fields are varchar, not number. so they still appear with quotes

Comment: Great, I've seen your latest post, I have to find a way to remove the Backticks,